# WebAuthenticationDetails cannot be cast to class SimpleKeycloakAccount

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud

I have a problem about solving this issue when I call from one microservice to another one though rest template.
I used **Keycloak 18.0.2** version.

I got this issue shown below.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails and org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Here is my auth (not Keycloak) :

```
UserController | infoUser | auth toString : AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
: UserController | infoUser | auth getPrincipal : anonymousUser
```

Here is my method to call another service

```
private String getRoleInfo(){

        LOGGER.info("UserServiceImpl | getRoleInfo is started");

        String result = this.restTemplate.getForObject(USER_BASE_URL + "/info",String.class); // ISSUE HERE 

        LOGGER.info("UserServiceImpl | getRoleInfo | role result : " + result);

        return result;
    }
```

Here is my code snippets shown below.

```
@GetMapping("/info")
    public ResponseEntity<?> infoUser(){

        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser is started");

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | auth toString : " + auth.toString());
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | auth getPrincipal : " + auth.getPrincipal());

        KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal(); // ISSUE HERE
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();

        String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
        String email = accessToken.getEmail();
        String lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
        String firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
        String realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();
        AccessToken.Access access = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
        Set<String> roles = access.getRoles();

        String role = roles.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.equals("ROLE_USER") || s.equals("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                .findAny()
                .orElse("noElement");

        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | username : " + username);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | email : " + email);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | lastname : " + lastname);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | firstname : " + firstname);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | realmName : " + realmName);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | firstRole : " + role);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(role);
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here is the image : [Link](https://ibb.co/HDmX755)

Comment: How is auth defined?

Comment: Instead of using wildcard for the `ResponseEntity`, specify it to be `String`

Comment: I mean the return type of the controller, did you tried changing the `ResponseEntity<?> -> ResponseEntity<String>`

Comment: auth looks like  is not a String so you cannot cast it. Could you share its class and how is it created?

Comment: Did you try adding `toString()` 
(this.restTemplate.getForObject(USER_BASE_URL + "/info",String.class)).toString()

Comment: @FrancisG I'm calling with an anonymousUser and not using the user you authenticated. Perhaps, I cannot pass the principal from managementService to userservice. I think this is my issue. How can I do that?

Comment: I tried to add an auth Token to Request Header for Token spreading through services
but I still got the same error. @FrancisG

Comment: @faried What's the class of 'auth' ? Its auth.getPrincipal() is returning a String. You cannot cast it to another object! I think solution it is not trying to add stuff, but fix throught another way. The project info should be on stackoverflow, not on external site.

Comment: @FrancisG I cannot fix it.

Comment: @fariead sorry I left you out, let me try fixing it later